# Spring Cloud Config Asymmetric encryption error on Unix Machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, asymmetric

I got the following response while trying to encrypt using Asymmetric encryption on unix machine

```
{
    "description": "The encryption algorithm is not strong enough",
    "status": "INVALID"
}
```

**localhost:8012/encrypt**

This url response ok  but application work on windows operating system.

response
[image]

**10.301.332.31:8012/encrypt**

This unix machine and application response as algorithm is not strong enough
reponse is correct

[image]

Comment: Any logs or stack traces on server with error?

Comment: when sended request to localhost/encrpyt is typing o.s.c.c.s.e.EncryptionController: Encrypted data .         But send request to unix machine any log belongs to controller.

Comment: " If you get the error {"description":"The encryption algorithm is not strong enough","status":"INVALID"} when performing the POST /encrypt request, this is probably because your encrypt.key is in the wrong file. Make sure it is in the bootstrap.properties."

Comment: But I am not using symmetric key. I am using asymmetric key and KeyStore, password, alias are located in bootsrap.yml file